# How to reduce the header image height in WordPress Twenty Seventeen theme

Tags: html, css, wordpress

WordPress Twenty Seventeen theme comes with full page header image. I would like to reduce the size of the header image to a more typical header size that fills in only part of the screen and remove the parallax effect.

Comment: [Related question on WordPress Development SE](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/259007/128485)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in Twenty Seventeen theme's function file you can modify header width/height, it is defined as below mentioned function.

```
add_image_size( 'twentyseventeen-featured-image', 2000, 1200, true );
```

for above function you have to adjust the height in the css also, you can also adjust height like below example.

```
.has-header-image.twentyseventeen-front-page .custom-header, .has-header-video.twentyseventeen-front-page .custom-header, .has-header-image.home.blog .custom-header, .has-header-video.home.blog .custom-header{height: 75vh !important;}
```

add !important in the height or here  you can also change height of the header.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I edited the file wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen/functions.php, but these is no effect on the header image, even selecting another image to make sure the change propagates. THese seems to be something else that controls the size of this theme element.

Comment: Please also check the header image css, i have one more suggestion for adjusting height of the header. see line no 1638(if it's default css of the theme Twenty Seventeen) Please see the edited answer above.

Comment: No Problem! Thanks for the feedback, i'm glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove the header image by going to Themes > Customize > Media.
2. Add a header background image by inserting the following code in Theme > Customize > Additional CSS:

```css
  #masthead {
    background-image: url(“<insert url of your image>”);
    background-size: 100%;
  }
```